# Heroku: Manage auto-deployment using Platform API or CLI

Tags: heroku

I have a number of apps setup in Heroku, some configured to auto-deploy from github repos, and some configured to manually deploy by pushing to Heroku app repos.

While this works OK, I would like a way to be able to configure/view the auto-deployment settings from a script, using either the Platform API, or heroku cli.

I haven't been able to find an endpoint that actually exposes this information for an app.

I can get data about the builds and releases for an app, but I can't find a way to actually find out how a particular build was triggered.

I have a release script that I use to trigger builds for apps in our different environments. However I would like it to be able to exclude apps from the manual build, where auto-deployment is enabled.

Does anyone know how to get at the auto-deployment configuration for an app from the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. The GitHub Sync API is not exposed publicly.

You could reverse-engineer the HTTP calls the Heroku Dashboard is making to setup your apps, but that could change at any moment without notice.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed to know. Eventually we're going to setup a proper CI process, so I'll just start converting our apps to all be triggered from the release script, rather than using the auto github to heroku deployment.